# State var inside For-Loop not updating its Text() value on screen

Tags: swiftui

Expected result is updating the @State value inside the for loop would update the text value displaying the @State var.

The actual result is @State var only updates after the for loop is complete.

What I was trying to do was call a function that looped thru a bunch of pdf pages and processed them into a UIImages array. It can take a while so I was going to have a @State value that let the user know what the current page number and max page number were. But changing the @State value did not update the text label, not until the function had completed and returned did the value get updated to 100/100, never got 1...99/100.

I simplified the problem into a for loop with a sleep to try and understand it better and after several hours of googling and trying different methods, I am still at a loss. If someone could enlighten me on what I am missing that would be great.

Note: On all attempts, I can see the log printing the `i` value 1-10 as expected.

Attempt A:

Text() never says "-1" jumps straight from "" to 10 after 10 seconds is up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIteration: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(currentIteration).padding()

            Button("Find File") {
                currentIteration = String(-1)

                for i in 0...10 {
                    print(i)
                    currentIteration = String(i)
                    sleep(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt B:

Text() immediately says "-1" then jumps straight from "-1" to 10 after 10 seconds is up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIteration: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(currentIteration).padding()

            Button("Find File") {
                currentIteration = String(-1)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for i in 0...10 {
                        print(i)
                        currentIteration = String(i)
                        sleep(1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt C:

Becuase of Attempt B I figured wrapping DispatchQueue... around the value set inside the for loop would do the trick, but no dice.

Text() immediately says "-1" then jumps straight from "-1" to 10 after 10 seconds is up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentIteration: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(currentIteration).padding()

            Button("Find File") {
                currentIteration = String(-1)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for i in 0...10 {
                        print(i)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            currentIteration = String(i)
                        }
                        sleep(1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope one of you can point me in the right direction on figuring this out.
Thank you

Comment: You are likely freezing the thread since you are staying on the main thread for the sleeping . You should read up on asynchronous methods.

Comment: SwiftUI will only update the UI on the next run loop. You never get to the next run loop during your `for` loop because you never cede control of the main thread. What is your actual goal here? To see the number changing on the screen with 1 second intervals in between?

Comment: @loremipsum I think you are correct, I just tested a couple of 1-5 seconds DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter and it does update the values as expected.

Comment: jnpdx: Actual goal was a function triggered by a .onChange event that processed a bunch of pdfs. I noticed that inside that func I was updating the @State var and it was not reflected on screen so I started playing around with that concept and got this ^. Of course the sleep(1) inside this example would actually be a time consuming loop of pdfPage -> UIImage logic inisde the original function.

Comment: If either of your (loremIpsum/jnpdx) want to post an answer with your comment I can mark that as the accepted answer since you guys clarified the point I was missing.

Comment: Move the work (converting the pages to images) to a separate thread and dispatch calls to update the UI on the main thread when iterations are done.

Comment: Jnpdx: That’s exactly what I am planning to do next based off yours and loremIpsum’s feedback. Thanks for your help, I’ll update once I get back to my computer and can make the changes.

Comment: Yup that fixed it. 

The .onChange now wraps the function call inside a DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userIntiated).async { … }  and then the function call wraps the @State var updates inside of .main.async {…}. 

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are freezing the thread since you are staying on the main thread for the sleeping.